# Where was Harry's cloak while he was at Malfoy Manor?

Tags: harry-potter, invisibility-cloak

When Harry, Hermione and Ron got captured and taken to Malfoy Manor, leaving all their belongings behind in their tent, **where was his invisibility cloak?**

Why didn't they use it as part of their plan to escape? If they did leave it behind, how did they get it again?

Comment: it was in hermiones purse

Comment: Before escaping from Lovegood's house, they used the cloak then disapparate. And before the part where the snatchers came for them, Hermione hid it inside her magical concealed purse.

Comment: @Himarm - It was indeed.

Answer (score 6):

They were storing the Cloak in Hermione's magic purse. Presumably it was in there the entire time they were in the Manor.

### Before capture

> *But he scarcely heard Hermione: **he had pulled out his Invisibility
>   Cloak** and was running it through his fingers, the cloth supple as
>   water, light as air. He had never seen anything to equal it in his
>   nearly seven years in the wizarding world.*

### During capture

> *As they had lost Perkins’s old tent on the night that the Snatchers caught them, Bill had lent them another one. It was now packed inside **the beaded bag, which, Harry was impressed to
>   learn, Hermione had protected from the Snatchers by the simple
>   expedient of stuffing it down her sock.***

### After capture

> *Harry bent down and the goblin clambered on to his back, his hands
>   linked in front of Harry’s throat. He was not heavy, but Harry
>   disliked the feeling of the goblin and the surprising strength with
>   which he clung on. **Hermione pulled the Invisibility Cloak out of the
>   beaded bag and threw it over them both.***